# JSON related error: Unexpected token o

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

My **database table**:

```
TABLE `events` (
    `event_id` INT(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `event_title` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `event_desc` TEXT,
    `event_location` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `event_requirements` TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
    `event_date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`event_id`)
```

**The goal**: When an event is selected in a select drop down menu, I would like to show the rest of the database data, which belongs to the event in a div below.
**The attempt** to solve the problem (in a MVC architecture):
Controller

```
  function index()
  {
      $overview_model = $this->loadModel('Events');
      $this->view->events = $overview_model->getEventTypes();
      $this->view->render('events/index');
  }
```

Model

```
  public function getEventTypes()
  {
      $sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM events");
      $sth->execute();

      $events = array();

      foreach ($sth->fetchAll() as $event) {
          $events[$event->event_id] = new stdClass();
          $events[$event->event_id]->event_id = $event->event_id;
          $events[$event->event_id]->event_title = $event->event_title;
          $events[$event->event_id]->event_desc = $event->event_desc;
          $events[$event->event_id]->event_location = $event->event_location;
          $events[$event->event_id]->event_requirements = $event->event_requirements;
          $events[$event->event_id]->event_date = $event->event_date;
      }

      return $events;
  }
```

View

```
    <!-- start event type selection --> 
   <div class="event-selection">
     <label>Choose an event:</label>
     <select id="select-event-type">
        <?php foreach ($this->events as $event) {
            // Using the event's ID as a value makes it easier for us to look up the selected event.
            echo "<option value='" .$event->event_id. "'>" .$event->event_title."</option>";
        }?>
    </select>

    <script>
        (function ($) {
            // Here we set the JavaScript variable 'events' to a JSON-encoded copy of the array we passed to the template, or null (if there are no events).
            var events = <?php echo (count($this->events) > 0) ? "JSON.parse(" .json_encode($this->events). ");" : "null"; ?>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#select-event-type').change(function() {
                    if (events) {
                        var event = events[this.value];
                        $('#event-details').html(event.title);
                    }
                });
            });
        })($);
    </script>   

    <!-- Start event-details -->
    <div id="event-details"></div> <!-- /#event-details -->

</div><!-- /.event-selection -->
```

On the page nothing happens when I change the drop down selection.
**Console output** (in chrome):

```
        <script>
            (function ($) {
                var events = JSON.parse({"1":{"event_id":"1","event_title":"event1","event_desc":"event1","event_location":"eventlocation","event_requirements":"event1","event_date":"2022-07-20 15:00:00"},"2":{"event_id":"2","event_title":"event2","event_desc":"event2","event_location":"eventlocation","event_requirements":"event2","event_date":"2015-04-20 15:00:00"},"3":{"event_id":"3","event_title":"event3","event_desc":"event3","event_location":"eventlocation","event_requirements":"event3","event_date":"2019-11-20 16:00:00"}});             $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('#select-event-type').change(function() {
                        if (events) {
                            // Now we can get the event details from the selected value.
                            var event = events[this.value];
                            $('#event-details').html(event.title);
                        }
                    });
                });
            })($);
        </script>
```

**The error**:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o

According to my research the line, producing the error is this one (in the view):

```
var events = <?php echo (count($this->events) > 0) ? "JSON.parse(" .json_encode($this->events). ");" : "null"; ?>
```

Is the JSON format correct in the console? Another thread suggested to rather use $.getJSON() than JSON.parse() but, since this is the first time I am using JSON, I am not quite sure how that would work in my situation.
I am very thankful for any kind of help!

Comment: Shouldn't you quote the value of `.parse`so it'll be a String ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var events = JSON.parse({"1":{"…
```

You are trying to parse a JavaScript object literal as if it was JSON.

Since you have to have a string in order to parse JSON, it gets converted into one giving you the equivalent of:

```
var events = JSON.parse("[object Object]");
```

That isn't JSON.

Just use the object literal directly:

```
var events = {"1":{"…
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! If I do this: `var events = <?php echo(count($this->events) > 0) ? json_encode($this->events) : "null"; ?>` It looks like this in the console: `var events = {"1":"event_id":"1","event_title":"event1",...` and I get this error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

Comment: The unexpected identifier error doesn't appear to be coming from that bit of code: http://jsbin.com/yepatevuso/1/edit?html,output

Comment: Okay! Thank you very much! Than I will keep digging!

Comment: One last question: Why is in the console $(document).ready.. on the same line as the JSON output? I read that there cannot be any white spaces in JSON. Is that the case with me?

Comment: Because nobody typed a line break character. It is not true that JSON cannot have white space in it. You aren't using JSON anyway, you're using the output of `json_encode` as if it were a JavaScript object literal (since JSON is a subset of JavaScript literal syntax when used in a standalone context).

Comment: If I leave JSON.parse out there is no ; at the end of the JSON code. The console output looks like this: `...,"event_date":"2019-11-20 16:00:00"}}  `

Comment: Ah, yes you should add a `;` after each JS statement.

Comment: Dumb question but how do I add a `;` to a php line, without ending it early? `<?php echo (count($this->events) > 0) ? json_encode($this->events) : "null"; ?>`

Comment: You need to add it to the JavaScript you *output*. Put it after the `?>`.